# Why parameter is not passed in resolved in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to pass parameter in resolver on button click .but I am getting error
**error**

```
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'next'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'next'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (https://angular-sxurk5.stackblitz.io/turbo_modules/@angular/router@6.0.0/bundles/router.umd.js:1422:16)
at CatchSubsc
```

passing param like that

```
 sclick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.sfrm.value.name);

    this.router.navigate(['next/'],{ queryParams: { value: this.sfrm.value.name} });

    }
```

using param like that

```
@Injectable()
export class TestResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    // id = 1

    return this.testService.getConfiguration(route.params.value);
  }
}
```

whole code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxurk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

when I click on `submit` button it show above error why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure the `next` route and not just the `next/:value` route.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HelloComponent },
  { path: 'next', component: NextComponent, resolve: { data: TestResolver} },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

In **TestResolver.ts** use `queryParams` instead of `params`

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  console.log('dd',route.queryParams.value)
  return this.testService.getConfiguration(route.queryParams.value);
}
```

Comment: why two routes ?

Comment: Maybe you need the `next/:value` route. If not, remove it.

Comment: when I remove this next/:value I am not getting value in resolver ``console.log('dd',route.params.value)

Comment: why `{ path: 'next', component: NextComponent },` it is required

Comment: where it is used ?

Comment: In your resolver use `console.log('dd',route.queryParams.value);` instead of `route.params`

Comment: I've updated the answer. Use the route with `resolve: ...` and use `queryParams` instead of `params`